# LogiXML Cross-Tab Table Headers not concatenating

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a crosstab data table, and my CrossTabColumnLabel consists of data from a lookup table in my oracle database. (By way of a Label)

I pull it out like so:

```
@Data.COLUMN_NAME~
```

in the Label Caption. Now when I do something like this:

```
@Data.COLUMN_NAME~ & @Data.COLUMN_NAME~
```

It acts as you would suspect and prints the name twice.

However, when I do try to concatenate a number, it does not print the number, only the & sign

```
@Data.COLUMN_NAME~ & @Data.NUMBER_COLUMN~
```

I have tried to pull it out of the database as a text value using Oracle's CAST function:

```
cast( NUMBER_COLUMN AS varchar2(30) ) as NEWVALUE
```

and tried this:

```
@Data.COLUMN_NAME~ & @Data.NEWVALUE~
```

But still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use values in the CrosstabLabelColumn, these Data Columns must be included in your Crosstab Filter as  elements so that you can reference the token values in your Crosstab table.

For more details, you might find this article helpful:

http://devnet.logixml.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1035

Regards,

David